# Monitored parallel mapping across a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

This code maps a function over a dataset in parallel *in a monitored fashion*, and returns the result in the variable out.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm, trange
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
import math

n_jobs = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 200))
chunk_size = 32
n_chunks = min(len(df), int(math.ceil(len(df) / chunk_size)))

def func(x): # do something
    return x+1

out = Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=0)(
            delayed(func)(
               df[i * chunk_size: (i + 1) * chunk_size]
             )
             for i in trange(n_chunks))
```

What are the pros and cons of this approach? Are there better approaches? What if I needed to map in-place?